# Retour d'un expat : rapat ou repat ?

Tags: verbes

J'ai récemment (avril 18) entendu sur France2 un sujet sur les « *repatriés* », ce qui impliquerait l'existence du verbe « *repatrier* ». Or il semblerait que *repatrier* est un barbarisme. La forme correcte serait *a priori* « rapatrier. » D'ailleurs en tant qu'expat, on les appelle les « rapats » entre nous.

Voir source : TLFi
["Réinstaller chez soi ou dans un lieu donné."](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapatrier)

Êtes-vous d'accord avec ça ?

Answer (score 5):

Les personnes qui utilisent *repatrié* aujourd'hui le font peut-être à cause de l'anglais *repatriated* mais on ne peut pas dire que ce mot soit un barbarisme puisque le verbe original latin est bien *repatriare* et qu'il a donné *repatrier* en moyen français, encore attesté dans d'anciens dictionnaires comme par exemple le [Dictionnaire de mots nouveaux](https://books.google.fr/books?id=prVfAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22repatri%C3%A9%22&hl=fr&pg=PP11#v=onepage&q=%22repatri%C3%A9%22&f=false) (1845):

[image]

celui de Bescherelle (ici l'édition de 1856) :

[image]

ou [le Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/repatrier) (1874)

> **repatrier**
>   (*re-pa-tri-é*), je repatriais, nous repatriions, vous repatriiez ; que je repatrie, que nous repatriions, que vous repatriiez v. a.
>   Reconduire dans la patrie.
>   **REMARQUE**
>   On dit aujourd'hui rapatrier.
>   **HISTORIQUE**
>   XVe s.
>   *Votre mariage vous fera repatrier [retourner dans votre pays]*, Louis XI, Nouv. XLII.
>   **ÉTYMOLOGIE**
>   Lat. repatriare, qui avait donné dans l'ancienne langue repairer, repairier, de re, et patria, patrie.

On peut donc considérer que *rapatrier* est d'un certain point de vue un barbarisme qui a réussi, et qui a même fini par supplanter la forme originale.

C'est d'ailleurs l'avis exprimé dans le [journal de la langue française et des langues en général](https://books.google.fr/books?id=o_AzAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA651&ots=B1UJKYM_Ur&dq=repatri%C3%A9&hl=fr&pg=PA650#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1838) qui critique la nouvelle acception de *rapatrier*:

[image]

D'après la question et une rapide recherche, on peut observer que cette forme est en train de revenir subrepticement sous l'influence de l'anglais (*repatriate*), un anglicisme qui reprend donc la forme ancienne du français...

***Repatrié*** est aussi décrit comme néologisme (qu'il n'est pas) pour désigner les africains qui retournent dans leur pays d'origine après un séjour prolongé à l'étranger. Il est possible que ce mot ait été choisi pour marquer une différence avec ***rapatrié*** qui est fortement associé aux rapatriés d'Afrique du Nord ayant quitté les pays du Maghreb après la décolonisation en 1962.

Voir par exemple [cette page](https://miscellanees01.wordpress.com/2018/05/20/senegal-repats/) à propos d'une émission de France Inter :

> « Repatriés » africains, ce néologisme désigne la diaspora africaine qui a choisi de revenir dans son pays d’origine.
>   ...
>   Il y a avait les « expats », il y a désormais les « repats »

Comment: Source : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapatrier, peux-tu me donner une source sérieuse récente pour "repatrier" ?

Comment: Je ne peux pas car *rapatrié* est la seule forme correcte aujourd'hui, ayant supplanté *repatrié*.

Comment: [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/repatrier) est plus récent de quelques années (1873-1874,1878).

Comment: @mouviciel C'est vrai, j'ai rajouté le Littré et quelques autres références.

Comment: Conclusion : si l'horloge s'est arrêtée, et que l'on se réfère au français du XIXè siècle, celui que l'on ne parle plus vraiment aujourd'hui, alors c'est `repatrié`... Pour tous les autres, pour ceux qui parlent le français en tant que langue vivante, alors c'est `rapatrié`. C'est donc Bibi qui est moderne pour une fois.

Comment: Tu oublies que l'une des caractéristiques d'une langue vivante, c'est justement de ne pas être figée. On ne peut donc pas exclure que *repatrier* ne reprenne un jour la place qu'il a perdue, ou au moins qu'il revienne en concurrence avec *rapatrier*.